# How to add a one to many column using lists in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, arraylist, pandas-groupby, one-to-many

The first list in "fav_colour" and "names" are from "Tower Hamlets".

The second list in "fav_colour" and "names" are from "Waltham Forrest".

Please see Script & CURRENT output Below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


fav_colour = [['blue', 'yello', 'indigo', 'jasmine', 'green', 'black'], ['yellow','purple', 'red', 'beige']]

names = [['melanie', 'jess', 'sean', 'tom', 'arjun', 'brandon'],['scotty', 'harry', 'chloe', 'emily']]

boroughs = ['Tower Hamlets','Waltham Forrest']

No_of_rows = [len(name) for name in names] #using length to repeat rows in some way??


indexs4 = list(range(0,2))
df1 = [pd.DataFrame(zip(names[i], fav_colour[i], boroughs[i]), columns = ['names','fav', 'boroughs']) for i in indexs4]
df = pd.concat(df1)
```

"fav_colour" and "names" have a one to one relationship.

"names" and "fav_colour" have a one to many relationship with boroughs

I want to make a one to many relationship with "fav_colour", "name" and "boroughs" as columns like below:

Desired Output:

```
     names      fav boroughs
0  melanie     blue   Tower Hamlets
1     jess    yello   Tower Hamlets
2     sean   indigo   Tower Hamlets
3      tom  jasmine   Tower Hamlets
4    arjun    green   Tower Hamlets
5  brandon    black   Tower Hamlets  
0   scotty   yellow    Waltham Forrest
1    harry   purple    Waltham Forrest
2    chloe      red    Waltham Forrest
3    emily    beige    Waltham Forrest
```

Current Output:

```
 names      fav boroughs
0  melanie     blue        T
1     jess    yello        o
2     sean   indigo        w
3      tom  jasmine        e
4    arjun    green        r
5  brandon    black         
0   scotty   yellow        W
1    harry   purple        a
2    chloe      red        l
3    emily    beige        t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

fav_colour = [['blue', 'yello', 'indigo', 'jasmine', 'green', 'black'], ['yellow','purple', 'red', 'beige']]

names = [['melanie', 'jess', 'sean', 'tom', 'arjun', 'brandon'],['scotty', 'harry', 'chloe', 'emily']]

boroughs = ['Tower Hamlets','Waltham Forrest']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['names','fav', 'boroughs'])

for i  in range(len(fav_colour)):
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names[i],fav_colour[i])),columns=['names','fav'])
    tmp["boroughs"] = boroughs[i]
    df = df.append(tmp,ignore_index= True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most sophisticated approach, but it does the trick.

First, I would organise the data in a dictionary with two keys: 'Tower Hamlets' and 'Waltham Forrest':

```
pre_dict = {
    borough: {'fav': cols, 'names': names} 
    for borough, cols, names in zip(boroughs, fav_colour, names)
}
```

Then I would iterate over the dictionary and create a dataframe from each key-value pair:

```
cont = []
for k, v in pre_dict.items():
    pre_df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    pre_df['borough'] = k
    cont.append(pre_df)

pd.concat(cont)

#       fav    names          borough
#      blue  melanie    Tower Hamlets
#     yello     jess    Tower Hamlets
#    indigo     sean    Tower Hamlets
#   jasmine      tom    Tower Hamlets
#   ...
#       red    chloe  Waltham Forrest
#     beige    emily  Waltham Forrest
```